# How can i make dynamic text columns on my website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a text dynamically devided over two columns. So i want half of the text to be in one column and the other half right next to it regardless how long the text is.
What is the best approach to this?

Comment: [Please read this before asking questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this goes hold but if you need help check this http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/dPUmZ/313/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

```
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css

```css
div {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
     column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque aliquam molestie nisi lacinia maximus. Sed malesuada lacus dignissim aliquam viverra. In fringilla magna ut mi ornare mattis. Pellentesque interdum aliquam arcu ac egestas. Vestibulum dui tellus, luctus vitae malesuada vel, rhoncus sed velit. Pellentesque congue, mi eget gravida egestas, lectus orci blandit sapien, eu malesuada lorem leo eu felis. Duis porttitor volutpat augue feugiat hendrerit. Donec nibh lorem, lacinia ullamcorper auctor eu, efficitur vel risus.

Suspendisse potenti. Donec ullamcorper pulvinar vulputate. Nam interdum tristique efficitur. Donec ullamcorper mi sit amet mollis vestibulum. Donec tincidunt lacus a erat tristique, vitae convallis diam maximus. Maecenas imperdiet, leo sed convallis interdum, enim urna maximus purus, elementum condimentum metus est vel libero. Suspendisse id enim id nunc mattis accumsan. Nam molestie, odio vel pretium blandit, tortor elit posuere turpis, quis hendrerit quam lorem sed elit. Nam a tortor ut felis facilisis ultrices et at lorem. Praesent nec lorem vel ligula sagittis luctus id non libero. Maecenas ut dictum massa, id volutpat diam. Donec id magna rutrum, pulvinar magna quis, tempus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse potenti. 
  </div>
```

Taken from :http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: why the -1? is it wrong?

Comment: I don't know, i cannot vote yet.. But it works fine! thanks for answering!

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/, which is a jQuery plug-in to try and simplify the process.

A CSS can be found at: [CSS dynamic responsive column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560796/css-dynamic-responsive-column-layout)